# Simple PHP code...?

Tags: php

I have this seemingly simple piece of PHP in my website:

```
<?php 
$_GET["sid"]; 
if ($sid=="83893")
  $survey="Survey Name";
?>
```

That should make `$survey` "Survey Name," right?

Later in my page, I have

```
<h3>Thank You For Participating In The <?php echo $survey; ?></h3>
```

If the user goes to `mypage.php?sid=83893`, instead of it echoing "Survey Name" it doesn't show anything?  Why is this?

As expected, if I simply put

```
Thank You For Participating In The <?php echo $_GET["sid"]; ?>
```

It writes the `sid`, but why won't it output `$survey`?

Comment: You don't have any variable $sid in your code. In your IF clause you should have $_GET['sid'] == "83893"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're never creating the variable `$sid` or assign anything to it.
Guess you're looking for `$sid = $_GET['sid'];` or simply `if ($_GET['sid'] == 83893)`.

Note that you should *check* whether `$_GET['sid']` actually exists before using it with `isset($_GET['sid'])`. Note also that you should turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/error%20reporting) during development, it would have helped you to catch this problem.

Answer (score 3):

$sid = $_GET["sid"];

Then it will work, as you never define what $sid is

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is

```
$sid = $_GET['sid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
<?php 
$sid = $_GET["sid"]; 
if ($sid == "83893")
  $survey="Survey Name";
?>
```

then later you can say:

```
<h3>Thank You For Participating In The <?= $survey ?></h3>
```